# Case When Structure

Tags: sql-server, case

Why does this not work?

```
UPDATE [REPORTING].[dbo].[dim_lite_Std_Suite_Upg] 
SET ProductHierarchyID = 
    CASE
        SUBSTRING(ArticleCode, 1, 4) IN ('Live') 
        AND SUBSTRING(ArticleCode,11,4) IN (Select lite from Lite_Ac)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(ArticleCode, 9, 2) = 'St' AND SUBSTRING (BundleArticleCode, 1, 3) IN ('BuS') 
          THEN '244218'
        WHEN SUBSTRING(ArticleCode,9,2) = 'Ed' AND SUBSTRING(BundleArticleCode, 1, 3) IN ('BuS') 
          THEN '244330'
        ELSE ProductHierarchyID
    END
```

As this part `SUBSTRING(ArticleCode,1,4) IN ('Live') AND SUBSTRING(ArticleCode,11,4) IN (Select lite from Lite_Ac)` applies to both `WHEN` conditions is there a way to combine it so that it applies to both when conditions.

The alternative would be to write:

```
CASE 
   WHEN SUBSTRING(ArticleCode, 1, 4) IN ('Live') AND SUBSTRING(ArticleCode, 11, 4) IN (SELECT lite FROM Lite_Ac) AND SUBSTRING(ArticleCode, 9, 2) = 'St' AND SUBSTRING(BundleArticleCode, 1, 3) IN ('BuS') 
     THEN '244218'
```

Comment: You cannot *"extract"* a common subexpression - you'll have to write out the whole `WHEN` clause

Comment: Why would you think it would work?    There's nothing in the CASE documentation that suggests it should.

Comment: No it does not, but I hoped for a kind of loophole here as it would be a very convenient way. No reason for whomever to downvote my question as it was properly raised...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have `Boolean expression` just after `CASE`. You can have it after `WHEN`.

For e.g. this is **incorrect**

```
CASE A = B
WHEN B = C THEN 1
WHEN A = C THEN 1 
ELSE 0
END
```

**correct** expression would be:

```
CASE 
WHEN A = B AND B = C THEN 1
WHEN A = B AND A = C THEN 1 
ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The TSQL language syntax does not support what you want. If it's common to all rows you can put it in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE [REPORTING].[dbo].[dim_lite_Std_Suite_Upg] 
SET ProductHierarchyID = 
    CASE
        WHEN SUBSTRING(ArticleCode, 9, 2) = 'St' THEN '244218'
        WHEN SUBSTRING(ArticleCode,9,2) = 'Ed'   THEN '244330'
        ELSE ProductHierarchyID
    END 
WHERE   SUBSTRING(ArticleCode, 1, 4) IN ('Live')
        AND SUBSTRING(ArticleCode,11,4) IN (Select lite from Lite_Ac)
        AND SUBSTRING (BundleArticleCode, 1, 3) IN ('BuS')
```